# Excel/Google Sheets: How to find (and count) first occurrences of a string

Tags: excel, google-sheets, pivot-table, spreadsheet

I have a list of purchases in a spreadsheet (CSV, so I can do the operation in Excel or Google Sheet, doesn't matter), so single lines that include data like:

`Date, Customer Email, Customer ID, Product`

I'm struggling to find out the **number of *new* customers per month**.

I'm familiar with pivot tables, however, I *think* I need a formula or helper table prior to pivoting the data?!

Basically I need to identify when each Customer Email or Customer ID occurs for the first time.

The ideal desired output would be a (pivot?) table like:

```
Month, Number of new customers
January 2019, 100
February 2019, 120
...
```

As you can see I'm struggling a bit to put it into words, which might also be the reason why I'm struggling to find the answer that I'm sure is already out there.

Does anyone know what I mean, and have a hint in regards to how to achieve it?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: In Excel, if you got a CSV, you can do Text To columns to separate each field. After that, create a Pivot Table and take field `Customer Email` into Rows Section of the Pivot Table. The output will be a list of **unique** emails.

Comment: @FoxfireAndBurnsAndBurns I understand what you mean, this way I would get all unique emails. However how could I find out the new emails (= new customers) that appear first in a certain month?
I'm clarifying my question in regards to the desired output

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution here: https://exceljet.net/formula/new-customers-per-month

Bascially:

1. Create a helper column that gives a 0 or 1 if the customer is new with something like `=(COUNTIFS($B$5:B5,B5)=1)+0`
2. Then create a pivot based on that data

Comment: Wouldn't that assume you always have the data sorted? So if you sort by another column it messes up your pivot.

Answer (score 0):

1. Add a column with the following array formula (Ctrl + Shift + Enter);

   `{=MIN(IF(Customer ID Column=Customer ID cell,Date Column))}`
2. Create a pivot table and select the option "Add to data model".
3. Put your new column in the "Rows" section.
4. Put customer ID in the "Values" section and change to "Distinct count".

This now gives you the distinct, earliest, count your customer ID appears.